# Integration of dialogflow with personal knowledge graph using neo4j

Tags: neo4j, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, knowledge-graph

I want to integrate Google **DialogFlow chatbot with a personal knowledge graph, that may be stored as a neo4j graph or may be stored in other forms like RDF triplet or maybe using some other databases.**

How to do that?

If anyone has any leads regarding this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but I would implement an agent with serverless functions that could call a Neo4j Database. Also, if you want to work with RDF and Neo4j, there is the Neosemantics plugin;

- https://neo4j.com/labs/neosemantics/
- https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9Hl4pk2FsvX-5QPvwChB-ni_mFF97rCE